# Where to put file for storing sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I want to utilize the sharedpreferences in my app, but in all of the tutorials and documentation in the internet I can not find out where to put the file that I am suppose to use.

What I mean is, when trying to access it as so:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "AOP_PREFS";
SharedPreferences  settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I don't know where to put the file AOP_PREFS.xml so that my class can use it. Am I missing something and I'm not suppose to be creating a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here. If your code is in an activity class, you just need to call `getSharedPreferences(int)` instead of `getSharedPreferences(String, int)`. You get the preferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences (Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Or you can use the `PreferenceManager` class to get the shared preferences as well:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

where `this` is a `Context` object.

You can retrieve a string from the preferences using a key (In this case, `myString`).

```
prefs.getString ("myString", "");
```

If you have not saved a string with the `myString` key, the second parameter will be returned.

This is how you can save a string into the preferences:

```
prefs.edit().putString ("myString", "Some String value");
```

The first parameter is the key, and the second is the value. Self-explanatory!

**NOW REMEMBER!** Every time you save something, call `apply()`!

```
prefs.edit().putString ("myString", "Some String value").apply();
                                                         *******
```

And that's all you have to know about shared preferences!

Answer (score 0):

Using SharedPreferences, the file is automatically created in the `files` folder in internal storage of your app, so you don't need to explicitly do anything to create the file.

The file in this case will be `AOP_PREFS.xml`.

You can also just use "default" SharedPreferences, which will be stored in an xml file with the package name of your app.

Example of Writing to Default SharedPreferences:

```
    SharedPreferences sp =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putLong("some_value", someValue);
    editor.commit();
```

Reading:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Long someVal = sp.getLong("some_value", 0);
```

Note that unless you have a rooted device, you won't be able to view files in internal storage.